# How to iterate over a pointer to an array (int*) when size is not known?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I was looking through some coding problems and I've come across a problem where the input array is given as "int*" instead of vector.

This made me question how to iterate through this array **if we didn't know the size:**

```
vector<int> cellCompete(int* states, int days) 
{
    // my try: 
    for (; *states; states++ ) {
        cout << *(states) << " ";
    }

    vector<int> testArray;
    return testArray;
}
```

As you can see i've tried a simple way to iterate over the array, trying to check if the pointer would return nullptr at a point.

Example:

```
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0] returned "1" as output
[1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1] returned "1 1 1" as output.
```

However, this approach worked in the following example:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main () {
   // an array with 5 elements.
   double balance[5] = {1000.0, 2.0, 3.4, 17.0, 50.0};
   double *p;

   p = balance;

    for (; *p; p++ ) {
        cout << *(p) << endl;
    }

   return 0;
}
```

This is the question https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/active-inactive-cells-k-days/ but I cannot share the link for where I've come across the question because it is confidential. In the version that I had to solve, the function input was "int*" instead of other options.

**Extras**:
On the same website, my approach worked for another question with similar input:

```
int generalizedGCD(int num, int* arr)
{
    // WRITE YOUR CODE HERE  
    for (; *arr; arr++ ) {
        cout << *(arr) << " ";
    }

    return 1;
}
```

where the input examples were:

[2, 3, 4, 5, 7] and [2, 4, 6, 8, 10]

Is there a more reliable way to iterate through a pointer to an array **when we do not know the size** of the array?

None of the sources I've found online give a way to iterate **without knowing the size.**

I wanted to express that this question did indicate the size of the array but it just made me think if there is a way to iterate without given size.

Comment: There is literally no difference in the access of elements between a `int*` and a `int[10]`. Just use `for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) cout << arr[i];`

Comment: There is no way of iterating over something pointed to by a raw pointer unless the thing pointed to has a  defined terminating value, such as the zero at the end of a c-style string, or if you know the size.

Comment: @NeilButterworth I see, thank you that actually makes sense, both of these questions did give the size of the array in some way, I was wondering if there is a way to iterate over the array without knowing the size but I guess not.

Comment: Since you use C++, you could use templates to "pass" the size of an array (a *real* array, and not a pointer). Like e.g. `template<size_t N> int generalizedGCD(int num, int (&arr)[N]) { ... }`. Then you pass a reference to the actual array, with a known size.

Comment: Or start using [standard containers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container) instead of C-style arrays, like [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) or [`std::array`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array).

Comment: I am not trying to learn the right way to do it in this question, I just came across a question with "int*" as an input and started wondering if I can iterate through the array without actually knowing the size. But I'm sure someone else can benefit from your advice @Someprogrammerdude

Comment: Are you sure that in that thing you stumbled upon, there is no other thing that tells the program the size? Aside from a terminating value maybe some global constant?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there isn't.

You either need to have some kind of a terminating character, like in null-terminated strings or explicitly provide the size.

Besides your approach does not work and is not safe.
`*states` will not tell you if your pointer is `nullptr`. `operator*` is dereferencing and taking value of the object referenced by the pointer. That is why your cycle stops once it hits a `0` value in your array. If you do not have any zeroes in the array, the cycle will go on until going out of the allocated space for you array, and you will have an unaddressable access resulting in undefined  behavior, because you will be accessing memory, which could be used for something else, or even worse could be read-only or outside process's address space, causing a crash.

To take the actual value of the pointer (the address), you need to check `states` instead of `*states`, but it will not be `nullptr`. The value of the variable `states` is just some  number(which is equal to the address of the memory where the array is written).